# xamarin forms UWP app - after saving a file locally, sometimes it locks

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, system.io.file

**Background Information**

I have a c# xamarin forms application where I allow users to download files from Sharepoint. I'm saving the stream to a local folder on the windows desktop. Once the download is completed, I'd like for the users to be able to click on the file and open it.  Currently, when I try to open the file, I get errors saying that the file is in use by another application or user.

The download itself seems to be working fine.

Here's the code:

```
 try
 {
      using (var stream = await App.GraphClient.Sites[TestSiteId].Drive.Items[listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
      {
         var driveItemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name);
         var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);
         stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         stream.CopyTo(driveItemFile);
         stream.Dispose();
      }
      DisplayAlert("Download", listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name + " successfully downloaded", "OK");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Download failed with: " + ex.Message);
      DisplayAlert("Error", listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name + " failed with: " + ex.Message, "OK");
 }
```

**What I've Tried**

As you can see, I have everything wrapped inside a "using{}" statement.
I'm also explicitly calling stream.Dispose();
I've also tried to replace the call to .Dispose with Close() but that doesn't make a diff either.

Comment: `driveItemFile` is also a Stream, but it was not disposed/closed.

Comment: You don't need to call `Dispose()` on resources created as part of a `using` statement.

Comment: I believe @JuanSturla has pointed out your actual mistake: wrap `driveItemFile = ...` in a `using` statement like your `using (var stream = ....)` and the file should not be locked.

Comment: yeah i upvoted @JuanSturla  for his comment cuz that solved the issue for me.  If you make it an answer, I can accept it

Comment: @dot It's great that it worked! I made it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `driveItemFile` is also a Stream, but it was not disposed/closed and it's the actual stream that creates and locks the file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `FileStream`?

```
try
{
    var driveItemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name);
    using (var stream = await App.GraphClient.Sites[TestSiteId].Drive.Items[listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
    using (var fs = new FileStream(driveItemPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Open))
    {
        var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
    }
    DisplayAlert("Download",  listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name + " successfully downloaded", "OK");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download failed with: " + ex.Message);
    DisplayAlert("Error", listItemAsDriveItem.DriveItem.Name + " failed with: " + ex.Message, "OK");
}
```